# Does this modular arithmetic equation hold?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Does this modular arithmetic equation hold:
$$a_1N_1+a_2N_2+a_3N_3+\cdots+a_mN_m \equiv a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_m \mod {N_1+N_2+N_3+\cdots +N_m+}$$

Answer (score 3):

No, suppose all $a_i=1,N_i>1$.

$N_1+N_2+...+N_m \not\equiv m \text{ mod }N_1+N_2+...+N_m  $

Answer (score 1):

$$3\cdot 3+2\cdot 2\equiv 13[5]\neq (3+2)[5]$$